# He told me yesterday that he couldn't have drunk the milk "two days before/two days ago" - What are the differences in meaning?

Tags: meaning, past-tense

**Example 1**

> He told me yesterday that he couldn't have drunk the milk **two days before** and it must have been somebody else.

**Example 2**

> He told me yesterday that he couldn't have drunk the milk **two days ago** and it must have been somebody else.

What are the differences in meaning?

Comment: "Two days before" implicitly refers to two days before when the speaker was speaking - or three days before now.  "Two days ago" refers to two days before now.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be different if the sentence is relating a story that happened in the past but is being told using the present tense (there's a grammatical term for that, but it escapes me at the moment).  So, if in relating the story, I say, "Yesterday, he tells me that he couldn't have drunk the milk two days ago and it must have been someone else," then "two days ago" refers to three days before now, as "yesterday" applies to the whole sentence, including the time referent for "ago" in "two days ago".

Answer (score 5):

This looks like an artificial sentence that raises the question of native speakers' imprecision over words like "ago" and "before".

I suppose that, assuming the speaker was very carefully choosing his words and was speaking on Friday, then "two days ago" would refer to Wednesday, and "two days before" could be understood as "two days before yesterday, ie Tuesday".  But when placed in this context it is confusing, for both the listener, the speaker, and the person whose speech is being reported.

In natural and unrehearsed speech such precision is not common and it would not be justified to assume the speaker was being this precise, for if the speaker did want to be precise, they would use day names or dates and not the inherently confusing references to days.

So these could be referring to Wednesday and Tuesday (correctly) or to Tuesday and Wednesday (arguably incorrectly).

Answer (score 3):

With **two days ago**, a listener wouldn't know if the "he" of the sentence was being quoted, or paraphrased with time-translation that is normal for paraphrasing. The listnener wouldn't knnow  if that time reference was relative to the time of this utterance, the "now" of speaker and listener, or relative to "his" earlier utterance, its time.

With **two days before** there would be no such ambiguity because  **two days before** cannot be relative to the "now" of an utterance.  It can only be relative to an explicitly mentioned  or implicitly understood past time:

> I saw him two days before.  <sup>unidiomatic without an explicit or implicit reference to a past point in time</sup>

This is valid:

> I went to Paris on New Years Day. I had been in London two days before.

However, when *unquantified* it can be relative to the present:

> I've been there *before*.

In other words, if I were to go there, it would not be for the first time; I would be going there *again*.